# Can we get IP banned even using Selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I am using `Python` to `scrape` pages. Until now I didn't have any issues. I use `Selenium` for this purpose, but i also do hear that people get IP banned from some websites. I didn't faced that. Those people used `beautifulsoup`, `lxml` and `requests` libraries...

Selenium feels like a user is using the browser and not the bots, but can it also *IP banned* from some sites?
I am also using a header user_agent as:

```
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) ' \
                 'Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36'
```

Comment: Yes. Usually being banned is about how many requests you make in a certain amount of time, doesn't matter what medium you're using to interact with the website. I have received temporary to full blown IP bans.

Comment: Yes you can be banned. Other scrapers change their user agent dynamically and use different ip addresses. It is often not possible to distinguish scrapers from normal users without severely limiting the site's functionality. A lot of scrapers do site rendering. More advanced scrapers hire people to solve captchas. It's a balance between how advanced your scraper is, how much effort the website maintainer is willing to spend fighting scrapers and how severe you want to limit honest user's UX on the website.

Comment: If you're scraping, it's probably because that data hasn't been made available to you via API. If it hasn't been made available to you via API, you're probably not supposed to access it in an automated fashion. Even when that's not spelled out in a site's terms of use -- which it often is -- you should never expect scraping to be a stable data collection method.

Answer (score -1):

yes, It depends on the requests you send to a website, usually while datascraping a website can get you banned using the user agent is a plus because some websites wont let you in if that is not set up
if you dont want to get banned use a proxy IP.